# django authentication fail search for registration/login.html

Tags: django, django-authentication

I try to add authentication for a page.

In my main url.py, i added:

```
url(r'^accounts/login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'test/login.html'}),
```

and in my view:

```
@login_required()
def result(request):
    ...
```

When I try to see the result view I am sent to the login page (good). When i enter a bad login/password there is an error because the template **registration/login.html** does not exist.

Why does django look for this template while I tell it to use **test/login.html**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding URL name

```
 url(r'^accounts/login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'test/login.html'}, name='login'),
```

This occurs because login view may use `reverse('login')` for redirect after failed login.